# React useEffect - Why property from closure object does't get updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the example below, why the fetch function from `obj` doesn't get updated with the new function I'm setting to it inside `useEffect`?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Example () {
  const obj = {
    fetch: () => {
      throw 'Not implemented!';
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    obj.fetch = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://my.url.com');
      console.log('Data:', data);
    };

    obj.fetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    // the button click is throwing "Not implemented"
    <button onClick={() => obj.fetch()}>Test</button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button click is throwing "Not implemented", it is because `Example` is being re-rendered prior to the button click. If you play with the sandbox of my code below, you'll find that the "Test" button works as intended so long as you don't click on "Trigger render". Your `useEffect` dependency array is only set up to execute on mount. A re-render creates a new `obj` which never gets the `fetch` function reassigned.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Example() {
  const obj = {
    fetch: () => {
      console.error("Not implemented!");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    obj.fetch = async () => {
      console.log("Implemented");
    };

    obj.fetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => obj.fetch()}>Test</button>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [renderTrigger, setRenderTrigger] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Example />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setRenderTrigger(prev => prev + 1)}>
        Trigger render
      </button>
      <br />
      {renderTrigger}
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit useEffect]

Comment: So you basically triggered an forceUpdate. Very clever.